# need amplifier circuit for load cell output(mv) to milliamps, for giving input to the PLC

Tags: amplifier

We need to convert load cell output (millivolt) to (4-20)milliamps, to give input to the PLC. Is there any IC Or circuit diagram to directly convert millivolt to milliamps?

Comment: I cut'n'pasted *M831 Electronic YZC 131* into google, and the first hit that came up was *this post*, and it's only 52 minutes old, impressive trawling google. The second hit was to an amplifier designed for this type of load cell, with either voltage or 4/20mA loop output, from datum-electronics. However, this site isn't about recommending specific bits of kit to buy, so what you'll need to do is build a differential amplifier to receive the bridge signal, then a V to I converter to send the loop current. Googling either of those could well help.

Comment: can you please explain that clearly?

Comment: I recommend you to buy the ready made industrial amplifier for that purpose.

Comment: But we have to design that by ourselves. Its our project. We can't buy the ready made amplifier. Can you please tell us idea to design that.

Comment: Try to google: Load cell amplifier schematics. But don't expect you will find an industrial amplifier, rather some hobby stuff with digital output or small signal output, not 4-20mA.

Comment: Yep, its called a resistor

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following simple circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWckpw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Rin resistors connect to your bridge outputs. The differential voltage gain of the amplifier is Rf/Rin. Its output voltage is applied across Rshunt, which causes that voltage/Rshunt of current to be sunk by Q1 collector. C1 is to ensure stability.

Obviously you will need to bias the circuit so the output current falls in the range 4mA to 20mA with your range of bridge inputs. It may be that you need more gain than is convenient with a single stage, an instrumentation amplifier configuration (google) will be better for very high gain.

Needless to say, the amplifier will need to be powered. Typically in 4mA to 20mA loops, and in fact the reason for the minimum current specification, is the amplifier power supply is taken from the loop current, this will mean that there also needs to be a minimum voltage that the loop supply will deliver, sufficient for the amplifier. The current output servo could be allowed to go down to 0mA in this case, with the power supply drawing a fixed 4mA. Or you could power it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Should your project requirements include a specification for Effective Number of Bits (ENOB) or Signal Noise Ratio (SNR) in the presence of any interference, such as Hfields from nearby battery chargers or switching regulators, or Efields from MCU clocks sharing your PCB or 117VAC power cords poorly routed, then your project risk-control will benefit from using the GARGOYLES' MODE of the free software tool Signal Chain Explorer ( robustcircuitdesign.com ).

Oh, forgot about the various VDD trash generators modeled in the PSI database.
Here is the builtin list of PowerSupply interferers:
[image]

Signal Chain Explorer defaults to Sensor->ADC signal Chain. Go to left margin, select "AMPS" and pick your gain-stage topology[double-click to insert]; edit the opamp choice, set gain resistors; on far right click "Update" to view SNR; click the "Gargoyles" on, select the interferers you wish to evaluate; click "I/C" to enable the interstage PCB trace (necessary to Hfield and to Efield modeling); click "Update" again to see how the ENOB/SNR changes; for details, enable the text output "Analysis Details".

If Thermal Noise becomes significant, or interferers remain strong, then either
(1) make the traces more compact [shorter, narrower, closer to GND plane]
(2) activate the coax-cable or twisted-pair from Sensor to first gain stage
(3) [most useful approach] add very-low-frequency LPF after the gainstage
[this presumes the high frequency interferers have not overloaded the OpAmp]

If power-supply trash is a problem, you'll need to alter the resistors, inductors, and capacitors in the LR-C-R-CCC VDD model; update the PSRR to the OpAmp; you may need to include some LDO benefit at low frequencies. LDOs provide little benefit at high frequencies, because the huge internal power dissipation transistor has lots of parasitics from Vin to Vreg, and only external discrete filtering cleans up the high frequency trash/spikes/ringing.